# How to place pdf widgets without spanning in Flutter - Flutter pdf package

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I am using [Flutter pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package for creating pdf files.

I want to create parts in it, but they are spanning across pages. I mean, For example, title remains in page 1 while content is placed in page 2.

Do you know how to place them together (All content of a part are placed in the same page)?

I tried Partition, Column, Wrap etc. But they are all mixed in from SpanningWidget. That's probably why they are spanned across pages.